# DeprecationWarning on stripe import in vscode

Tags: python, stripe-payments, python-import, importerror, flask-restful

I get this error message:

```
DeprecationWarning:
The stripe.app_info package is deprecated, please change your
imports to import from stripe directly.
From:
from stripe.app_info import AppInfo
To:
from stripe import AppInfo
```

But the thing is I dont have any import named "from stripe.app_info import AppInfo" I have searched the code thoroughly. My tests are not able to run because of this error and it worked last friday. Does anyone have a similar problem with stripe or does anyone know how to solve this problem since the error message I have doesnt really applie to my imports. maybe it is a third hand library of stripe?

I tried to run my test but the tests where not able to run because of the error

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/stripe/stripe-python/issues/1167

Make sure you update to the latest version of stripe-python (which at the time of writing is 7.8.2) to fix this. (https://github.com/stripe/stripe-python/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#782---2023-12-11)

> and it worked last friday

You most have either updated your Stripe library dependency since then, or you  changed how you treat `DeprecationWarnings`.